# Ag-Grid ServerSide on ServiceNow Service Portal

Tags: ag-grid, servicenow

Anyone has implemented ag-grid using ServerSide on ServiceNow Service Portal before?
I need to get some sample from yours.

I have problem where it doesnt load record by batch.
It straight away loads everything in the initial.

As you can see below **endRow **and **StartRow **are **undefined** from **getRows**
[output console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjSnk.png)

I tried copy almost exact code into ServiceNow Portal from this example

[Data loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKfMG.png)

FYI, i have no issue implemented **InfiniteRow** method